# Conditional logical condition in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame looking like this:

```
> testdf <- data.frame(x=rep(1:3, each = 3), y=rep(1:3))
> testdf
  x y
1 1 1
2 1 2
3 1 3
4 2 1
5 2 2
6 2 3
7 3 1
8 3 2
9 3 3
```

Suppose now that I want to select the rows in which the *combination* of (x, y) corresponds to any of the rows in

```
> conddf <- data.frame(x=c(1, 1, 3), y=c(2, 3, 1))
> conddf
  x y
1 1 2
2 1 3
3 3 1
```

So for this particular example, I would like to select rows (2, 3, 7). I stressed the word 'combination' above, because I think that is what making a correct formulation of the logical statement problematic for me. I have tried using some variants including the `%in%` command, but I haven't been able to formulate it such that it takes the combination of (x, y) into account. In some sense, the admissible values of y are conditional on the values of x. My original data set is quite large, so looping I would like to avoid.

Any ideas?

---

Edit: This seems to do what I want, but using a loop. I can't seem to get it into `subset()`or `sapply()`, though, so help with that would be sufficient!

```
testdf <- data.frame(x=rep(1:3, each = 3), y=rep(1:3))
conddf <- data.frame(x=c(1, 1, 3), y=c(2, 3, 1))
tempfun <- function(x) {ifelse(x[,2] %in% conddf$y[conddf$x == x[,1]], 1, 0)}
ind <- c()
for (i in 1:9) {
  ind <- c(ind, tempfun(testdf[i,]))
}
```

Comment: If I'm not missing something, this looks like just a basic merging operation. Try `merge(conddf, testdf)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg That worked like a charm. I'm surprised (and almost a little embarrassed having been using R for 3 years now) how simple the solution was. If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!